# How to extend a main controller within a meteor package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

What is the right way to extend a main controller within a meteor package?

This is my case, the main controller is inside the `app.js` file, located in

```bash
both/controllers/app.js
```

The content is

```js
AppController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'appLayout'
});
```

Inside *my-package* folder, I've created a `router.js` file

```bash
packages/my-package/lib/router.js
```

Below the content of the file, here came the question: why if I move the `DashboardController` declaration outside the Meteor.startup() function, it doesn't work?

```js
DashboardController = AppController.extend({}); // here doesn't work

Meteor.startup(function () {

    Router.route('/dashboard', {
        controller: DashboardController,
        name: 'dashboard'
});
```

The output is

```bash
ReferenceError: AppController is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why if I move the DashboardController declaration outside the
>   Meteor.startup() function, it doesn't work?

That's because of the load order of Meteor build process : every package JS files are loaded according to dependencies between them and only after the actual application code is executed (which makes sense).

The solution is to move your `DashboardController` inside a `Meteor.startup` block so that it's executed after the application code had a chance to define `AppController`.

You could also move your `AppController` inside an `application-core` or `application-controllers` local package of yours and depend on that package.